# How to create a fully functional user registration in WordPress?

Tags: login, wpdb, user-registration

I used many user signup plugins for users registration and they did good job, but the problem is, each website collects different data through user registration forms. In my case, the data collected was stored partially in the users table in the database. For example, I want the users to mention their institute but I find this data nowhere in the database later.
How do I create a fully functional user registration system in WordPress? I I can do a bit of PHP programming if that can help.

Comment: There are form plugins that will allow you to customize fields. So this should not be a problem.

Comment: @Scott I used a few of them and they register a user but I don't find some of the entries in the database. Username, email, password etc. are in the users table, where can I find the other, e.g. phone number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to create a custom registration form with HTML and send it to a PHP function that creates the user and then adds user meta data.

For example, the form:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>" method="post">
  <!-- TODO: add a nonce in here -->

  <!-- this "action" pipes it through to the correct place -->
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="custom_registration"> 

  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <input type="text" name="email" />
  <input type="text" name="institute" />
  <input type="password" name="password" />

  <input type="submit" value="Register" />

</form>
```

This is just an example, in reality you would want to add extra validation and nonce to prevent any naughty business. This was just the basic form idea.

Then in your functions.php file to receive the form you make a hook using `add_action()`, where the first parameter uses the format `admin_post_nopriv_`+[action]. The `nopriv` means that this is for non-logged in users to execute functions (which a user who is registering most likely would not be logged in)

This [action] needs to match the value of the hidden action field in our HTML form. Since we called it `custom_registration` then the hook would be `admin_post_nopriv_custom_registration`:

```
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_custom_registration', 'custom_make_new_user' ); // the format here is "admin_post_nopriv_" + [the hidden action you put in the html form]


function custom_make_new_user(){

  // TODO: validate the nonce before continuing

  // TODO: validate that all incoming POST data is OK

  $user = $_POST['username']; // potentially sanitize these
  $pass = $_POST['password']; // potentially sanitize these
  $email = $_POST['email']; // potentially sanitize these
  $institute = $_POST['institute']; // potentially sanitize these

  $user_id = wp_create_user( $user, $pass, $email ); // this creates the new user and returns the ID

  if($user_id){ // if the user exists/if creating was successful.
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id ); // load the new user

    $user->set_role('subscriber'); // give the new user a role, in this case a subscriber

    // now add your custom user meta for each data point
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'institute', $institute);

    wp_redirect('/thank-you'); // redirect to some sort of thank you page perhaps.
  }else{
    // user wasn't made
  }
}
```

That should do the trick. You could add any other user data you wanted by adding extra `update_user_meta();` - the first param is the user_id, second param is the meta_key, third param is the meta value. The neat thing about `update_user_meta()` is that if it didn't exist already it will make it, otherwise it will update an existing value.

Then to retrieve this data anywhere, you would write this:

```
$user_institute = get_user_meta($user_id, 'institute', true);
```

The third parameter of `get_user_meta` is useful because without it, or with it set to false by default, you would receive an array but with it set to true it returns a single value ready to use.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This was a great explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimate Member is generally one of the most popular ones to use, creating a user registration form manually is easy - the hard part to manage manually is the login and everything that comes with that (i.e. forgotten passwords, verifying email addresses etc. it's no easy feat!),

Custom fields for Ultimate Member are in the usermeta database table

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ultimate Member is one of the plugins I have used and the information are there in the usermeta table. What if I change the users table, add another column (e.g. institute) and then write my own code for registering user as per my requirements and place it as shortcode where I need? Is changing the table a good idea? and is placing shortcode of your own code instead of using a plugin a good idea?

Comment: Changing WordPress database table structure is not a good idea. Use usermeta table for additional information. You can always develop a custom plugin (if needed) to enhance the features.

Comment: Yes as above I wouldn't change the core wp tables - why is it you need them in the same table are you trying to export them from the database?